# Python 3 ImportError: cannot import name 'model selection' OS X 10.11.3, Anaconda

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, scikit-learn, anaconda

Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (x86_64)on OS X 10.11.3

```
>>> from sklearn import pipeline, model_selection

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'model_selection'
```

tried to:

upgrade six, sk-learn,

```
sudo pip uninstall python-dateutil
sudo pip install python-dateutil==2.2
pip2 install six -U
pip install --ignore-installed six
pip install --ignore-installed ipython
```

even reinstall the anaconda... 
Did NOT fixed.

Thanks for help

_________Updata________

I have checked that my six version is the newest one (**version** = "1.10.0")

> > > import sklearn
> > >
> > > sklearn.**version**
> > >         '0.17.1'

I found that there is no folder name "model_selection" in sklearn folder.  But there is this folder in  https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/3078d7d611329c46777d4004a1185a3626558efe/sklearn.

After install the dev version by

$ pip install git+git://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git

Successfully installed scikit-learn-0.18.dev0

And then run a script which runs successfully in 0.17.1, it shows error:

from .pairwise_fast import _chi2_kernel_fast, _sparse_manhattan
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Username/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise_fast.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Username/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise_fast.cpython-35m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found

Answer (score 4):

What version of scikit-learn are you using? It looks like the latest, when I install for Python 3.5, is 0.17.1.  Checking in the console:

```
import sklearn
sklearn.__version__
'0.17.1'
```

According to the documentation for this [version](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html) that "model_selection" package doesn't exist.  It does exist in the [dev version](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/classes.html).  This should be why it is complaining.